# Ошибка ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Access to undeclared static property: Kohana::$cache

Tags: php, kohana

Всем привет.

Помогите разобраться. Когда запускаю сайт, выдает ошибку, которую я не смог решить сам, т.к. я не понимаю особо в кохане. ) Ошибку выдает:

> ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Access
> to undeclared static property:
> Kohana::$cache

Заранее спасибо. )

Версия коханы: 3.3.1

Comment: Укажите версию Kohana.

Answer (score 1):

Ну видимо потому что в 3.3+ нет такого свойства. Есть статический метод Kohana::cache(). Видимо какой-то модуль был предназначен для более ранней версии коханы. Ну и вообще мало информации - что ругается, где ругается, ничего непонятно)